# Bash script to sort mp3 files by bitrate

Tags: linux, bash

I have taken this script
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/finding-corrupt-mp3s-in-library-632053/ which seems to work fine originally, and modified it into this one to list out the tracks lower than 320 kbps but I get an unexpected end of file error.
The commands alone seem to work fine though.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp3' -exec sh -c 'curfname="{}";\
      bitrate=`mp3info -r a -p "%f %r\n" "$curfname" | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}'`;\
      if [ $bitrate -lt 320 ];\
      then \
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate; \
      fi ' \; | tee ./lowbitrate.log
```

Can any helpful soul point out where I'm wrong?

Edit:

This is what I get

```
~/bin/mp3bitrate.sh ~/Music
}`;\
      if [ $bitrate -lt 320 ];\
      then \
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate; \
      fi : -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
}`;\
      if [ $bitrate -lt 320 ];\
      then \
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate; \
      fi : -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
}`;\
      if [ $bitrate -lt 320 ];\
      then \
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate; \
      fi : -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
}`;\
      if [ $bitrate -lt 320 ];\
      then \
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate; \
      fi : -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
}`;\
      if [ $bitrate -lt 320 ];\
      then \
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate; \
      fi : -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
}`;\
      if [ $bitrate -lt 320 ];\
      then \
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate; \
      fi : -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Ok I have changed the second line with:

```
bitrate=`mp3info -r a -p "%r\n" "$curfname"`;\
```

so that the awk is not needed as that was causing problems.
But now I have a comparison with a float and integer, changing the if statement with

```
if [ $(echo "$bitrate < 320" | bc ) -e 1 ]
```

returns: line 2: [: -e: binary operator expected

but running the command alone seems to work:

echo "234.54444444<320" | bc

returns 1, what is wrong now i wonder!

Comment: If you add the output of `mp3info` to your question, we'll have a better idea of how to parse it.

Comment: If you tell us in what way the script you have isn't doing what you want (wrong output? no output? core dump? error messages? something else?), we'll have a better idea of how to explain and fix it.

Comment: Shellcheck produces [13 findings](https://pastebin.com/qxTvqv8Y) for your code. You should fix them before continuing.

Comment: @jww did you check the one in the answer or the question?

Comment: oh yes you ran the old code. the last one in my answer seems good no? https://pastebin.com/CtNKKhz8

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mp3info -r a -p "%f has %r bitrate\n" ./*.[Mm][Pp]3 | awk '$(NF-1)<320'
```

How it works:

- `-p "%f has %r bitrate\n"` prints the info in the format that you want.
- `awk '$(NF-1)<320'` selects only those lines with a bitrate less than 320.

#### Improvement

The above will fail if a file name itself contains newlines.  The usual way to deal with this is to use NUL-separated output but, as far as I can tell, `mp3info` doesn't support this.  In our case, the output will never contain `/`.  This is because, although `/` can be part of a path, it is never part of a filename in `%f`.  Thus we can use:

```
mp3info -r a -p "%f has %r bitrate/" ./*.[Mm][Pp]3 | awk -v RS=/ '$(NF-1)<320'
```

#### Sample output

```
$ mp3info -r a -p "%f has %r bitrate/" ./*.[Mm][Pp]3 | awk -v RS=/ '$(NF-1)<320'
gd77-05-08d1t01.mp3 has 186.720474 bitrate
gd77-05-08d1t02.mp3 has 183.336975 bitrate
gd77-05-08d1t03.mp3 has 183.020111 bitrate
...
```

#### Recursing into subdirectories (secure version)

To recurse through the currect directory and all its subdirectories looking for file with mp3 extensions, we can use `find`.  The most secure approach is to use `find` with `-execdir`:

```
find . -iname '*.mp3' -execdir mp3info -r a -p "%f has %r bitrate/" {} +  | awk -v RS=/ '$(NF-1)<320'
```

For example:

```
$ find . -iname '*.mp3' -execdir mp3info -r a -p "%f has %r bitrate/" {} +  | awk -v RS=/ '$(NF-1)<320'
gd77-05-08d1t05.mp3 has 184.018967 bitrate
gd77-05-08d3t05.mp3 has 189.467697 bitrate
gd77-05-08d1t08.mp3 has 183.625366 bitrate
gd77-05-08d1t09.mp3 has 183.826721 bitrate
...
```

#### Recursing into subdirectories (less secure version)

If your `PATH` is "insecure," then use `find` with `-exec`:

```
find . -iname '*.mp3' -exec mp3info -r a -p "%f has %r bitrate/" {} +  | awk -v RS=/ '$(NF-1)<320'
```

This produces the same output:

```
$ find . -iname '*.mp3' -exec mp3info -r a -p "%f has %r bitrate/" {} +  | awk -v RS=/ '$(NF-1)<320'
gd77-05-08d1t05.mp3 has 184.018967 bitrate
gd77-05-08d3t05.mp3 has 189.467697 bitrate
gd77-05-08d1t08.mp3 has 183.625366 bitrate
gd77-05-08d1t09.mp3 has 183.826721 bitrate
...
```

Comment: if i substitute your line i get:

~/bin/mp3bitrate.sh ~/Music
/home/apaxio/bin/mp3bitrate.sh: line 3: NF-1: command not found
/home/apaxio/bin/mp3bitrate.sh: line 3: 320`;\
      if [ $bitrate -lt 320 ];\
      then \
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate; \
      fi : No such file or directory

Comment: @RKon The command I show should be your __complete__ solution.  There should be no `if` or `echo` statements or anything else but what I show.

Comment: oh all by itself it returns nothing?.. and how would it recurse into the folders of the music library sorry i cannot understand.

Comment: In your original code, you had `-maxdepth 1`.  That means that you explicitly did  __not__ want recursion.  If you do want recursion, then we will need to make a change.

Comment: great thank you! but i get this:
find: The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove the current directory from your $PATH (that is, remove ".", doubled colons, or leading or trailing colons)
What is the danger??

Also would you know, regarding my answer, what command would move all these found files <320 into a directory preserving folder structure?

Comment: @RKon Sorry about that!  I just added a version that will still work even if your `PATH` has `.` in it.  (The issue is that, if your `PATH` contains `.`, it may try execute any file named `mp3info` that is in your current directory instead of the version you were expecting.  This is a potential unpleasant surprise whether you are using `find` or not.)

Comment: Very nice all done in one line, thank you! But the other way i see the full path to where to look for the file.
Also now I'm trying to move all found mp3s to a sub-directory preserving their folder structure, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I have found a solution!

```
#!/bin/bash
#
find . -maxdepth 3 -iname '*.[Mm][Pp]3' -exec sh -c 'curfname="{}";\
      bitrate=`mp3info -r a -p "%r\n" "$curfname"`;\
      if (( $(echo "$bitrate < 320" |bc -l) ));\
      then \
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate; \
      fi ' \; | tee ./lowbitrate.log
```

Will successfully scan the location recursing down to depth 3, printing in the terminal and logging to file any mp3 files found with bitrate lower than 320 Kbps.

How would I go by to move each one of these files into a new directory preserving the original structure?
Because even if I do:

```
...
      then \
         location="${curfname:2}";\
         mv "$curfname" "lowbitrate/$location";\
         echo $curfname has $bitrate bitrate;\
...
```

I still need to mkdirs recursively, any ideas?

Comment: `mkdir -p missing/path/elems` will create any subdirs needed to make the specified path. Good luck.

Comment: Yes! one step closer, I now have to remove the filename from $curfname and I will be good!

Answer (score 0):

I need also to sort my mp3 by bitrate but i also need to copy it in another directory and i want to keep the original structure of my "Musique" folder. So i did that way. Certainly not perfect, but it's working ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
## That script search for mp3 with high bitrate (equal to 320) and copy it to another directory
## and keep the original file structure
mp3_path="/home/user/Musique/"
copy_path="/media/disk/"

while read FILENAME
do

    f=$FILENAME
    path=${f%/*}
    xfile=${f##*/}
    title=${xfile%.*}
    ext=${xfile##*.}
    directory=$(dirname "${FILENAME}")

    bitrate="$(mp3info -r m -p "%r\n" "${FILENAME}")"
    # cut "/home/user/Musique/"" from the full path to not recreate it
    path_to_create=$(echo ${directory:19})
    copy_path_to_create=$(echo "$copy_path$path_to_create")

    if [[ "$bitrate" -eq '320' ]] ; then

        echo "$bitrate - $FILENAME" >> /home/user/Musique/texte.txt
        mkdir -p "$copy_path_to_create"
        cp "$FILENAME" "$copy_path_to_create"
    fi

done < <(find "$mp3_path" -type f -name "*.mp3")
```